# Background Tasking

Tags: android, service

I need my app to run in background so it can start the alarm and send notification to the user.

I have created one more class called `LocalService.java` I extend it with Service and implemented these methods `onBind()`, `onStartCommand()` and `onDestroy()`, on my `MainActivity` I have created the whole application which gets the coordinates of the user and updates automatically so it will know when to start the task. The most important stuff is in `onCreate()` method, which is `mMap.setOnMapClickListener` ("mMap" is from `private GoogleMap mMap;`) also inside this are `mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener` and `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener`... BUT the task I want to start is `mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener`. How I can do this in the `LocalService.java` to run in the background?

Comment: Hate to ask this here but.. anyone ? :P

Comment: you can send broadcast to activity from service in onlocationchanged

Comment: Can you help me how to do that ?

Comment: post your  work i will try

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/Km0qvT0p Its the MainActivity, all this are under `onCreate()`

Comment: Any updates from you ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G5WFSqat

Comment: @kishorejethava Please if you have any updates share it here or you can contact me on my email address: stefannrafa@gmail.com BTW my eyes started to frying me... :/

Comment: put your location listener code inside service and call that service at time interval using alarm manager

Comment: Can you give me your facebook or something you have to chat ?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/kishore.jethava

Comment: Will changing the user location be useful?

Answer (score 3):

**Background Task In iOS8**

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if ([app respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)])
    {
                self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

//                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
//                                       ^{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


                if (self.bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
                {


                    NSLog(@"Marking bgTask as Invalid when we entered background");
                }
            });
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Huh i think i need Android xD